# IISExpress HTML5 Video IOS

Tags: ios, html, video, iis-express

Can anyone confirm whether there is a bug in IISExpress serving html5 video to IOS devices?

The following example markup:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="">
 <source src="/videos/example.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

I have:

- Added the MP4 MIME type
- opened the port for cross network access
- confirmed the video will play on any other device/browser apart from Safari on IOS.

Accessing the same file hosted on IIS7 works fine from Safari on IOS.

Comment: I have this exact problem with IIS Express 7.5: works on all other browsers and devices including Safari on OS X. Other than running full IIS, I haven't found any other solution.

Comment: Interestingly, Chrome on iOS does not work either.

Comment: Chrome on IOS is essentially just a wrapper around the ios webkit webview so that's not really surprising. Thanks for confirming though :)